# MongoDB aggregation and lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I  made the below query:

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      isActive: true,
      
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "shifts",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "employee",
      as: "shifts"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$shifts",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      
    }
  }
])
```

And now getting the below result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "621eedae92979fd8f0e9451d",
        "name": "Pallab Koley",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636b9fcbda6d2b17f5cae0",
            "month": "2022-05",
            "shift": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-05-01",
                    "shiftId": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "621eedae92979fd8f0e9451d",
        "name": "Pallab Koley",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636bb3cbda6d2b17f5cae2",
            "month": "2022-04",
            "shift": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-04-01",
                    "shiftId": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "62626a7446ba9a911a623b37",
        "name": "Pinki Das",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636ba4cbda6d2b17f5cae1",
            "month": "2022-05",
            "shift": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-05-01",
                    "shiftId": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I need to filter the data with the particular month I am adding

```
{
    $unwind: {
        path: '$shifts',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        "shifts.month": “2022-04”
    }
},
```

I am getting the result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "621eedae92979fd8f0e9451d",
        "name": "Pallab Koley",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636bb3cbda6d2b17f5cae2",
            "month": "2022-04",
            "shift": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-04-01",
                    "shiftId": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

But my requirement is that I need all other existing employees from the employees collection even also there is no record in shifts collection. Please help to get that.

Comment: can you provide an example of the data that is in the collection and the expected result? Is hard to understand just seeing what your output is and a description of what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is what you need.

1. `$match`  stage
2. `$lookup` stage
3. **Remove** `$unwind` stage.
4. `$project` stage - With `$filter` operator to filter the document in `shifts` array which `month` is `2022-04`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // $match ,
  // $lookup,
  // Remove $unwind
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      name: 1,
      shifts: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$shifts",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.month",
              "2022-04"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r9--3OlQNMB)